# How to Reverse Lookup in Redis?

Tags: nosql, redis

Is it possible to use Redis to lookup by key OR value?  I need to store a master list of email addresses, assign a UUID to each address, but be able to find the ID OR ADDRESS by using the other piece of data.  I cannot find a definitive "yes" or "no."  Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to create 2 hashmaps:

1. Hashmap from UUID to email (uuid_to_email)
2. Hashmap from email to UUID (email_to_uuid)

For example:

```
> hset uuid_to_email 39315120-9581-11e3-9c4e-0002a5d5c51b foo@bar.com
> hset email_to_uuid foo@bar.com 39315120-9581-11e3-9c4e-0002a5d5c51b
```

Then to retrieve the value, use the hashmap that maps from the value you have. If you have a UUID, use uuid_to_email:

```
> hget uuid_to_email 39315120-9581-11e3-9c4e-0002a5d5c51b
"foo@bar.com"
```

If you have an email, use email_to_uuid:

```
> hget email_to_uuid foo@bar.com
"39315120-9581-11e3-9c4e-0002a5d5c51b"
```

Comment: Hashes aren't designed to hold a large number of items so this approach is only valid if the use case is about a couple of hundreds addresses.

Comment: @ItamarHaber That's absolutely incorrect. Instagram, for example, [is storing hundreds of millions of records in HashMaps](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs). 

From that blog post, "we need to keep around a mapping of about 300 million photos back to the user ID that created them...We asked the always-helpful Pieter Noordhuis, one of Redis’ core developers, for input, and he suggested we use Redis hashes." Not only is it possible, it's the most efficient way to store that much data.

Comment: Also, @ItamarHaber, the published time complexity of hset and hget are O(1), so are you saying that's incorrect?

Comment: @uberdog excuse my english, Instagram doesn't store more than 1000 records in a HASH map, they divide the record id by 1000 (and discard the rest) and use the result value to set the HASH name.

Comment: @mzalazar That's correct & thanks for pointing that out. For their use case they needed the smallest memory footprint possible with the least CPU load on retrieval & they were willing to shard over multiple keys. For the average user of Redis, I would consider such an implementation to be premature optimization. I still maintain that it's incorrect to say that hashes aren't designed to hold a large number of items. The algorithm Redis uses to store hashmaps changes depending on the quantity of data held in it, by design. You can see details of the tradeoff [here](http://bit.ly/1vgnRuV).

Answer (score 2):

You have can store both key and value as combination of both

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET XXX:abc@yahoo.com XXX:abc@yahoo.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET YYY:xyz@gmail.com YYY:xyz@gmail.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys YYY:*
1) "YYY:xyz@gmail.com"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *:xyz@gmail.com
1) "YYY:xyz@gmail.com"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys XXX:*
1) "XXX:abc@yahoo.com"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *:abc@yahoo.com
1) "XXX:abc@yahoo.com"
```

**DRAWBACK:**: Even though it is very fast but it will block the server for that time, And also you will have to split it at application.

**Better Approach:-**: Store two keys this way your lookup will be very fast O(1) and you wont have to split at application level

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET XXX abc@gmail.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET abc@gmail.com XXX
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET YYY xyz@gmail.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SET xyz@gmail.com YYY
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> GET XXX 
"abc@gmail.com"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> GET abc@gmail.com
"XXX"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> GET YYY
"xyz@gmail.com"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> GET xyz@gmail.com
"YYY"
```

**DRAWBACK:** More Space

Comment: Using KEYS is not a recommended practice. The 2nd approach is the way to go about it.

Comment: I disagree that this is the best approach. Both of these methods pollute your root-level namespace and don't offer you a way of retrieving the complete set of email addresses or set of UUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use the power of redis sets. Since you want to be able to preserve space, it makes sense to use the hash keys combined with their values as reverse lookup sets that hold the indexes.

In the following example, I want to store information about a user's name, likes and where they live. I then want to be able to do searches such as
'Who lives in the uk and likes whisky?':

```
> incr key:user
(integer) 1

> hmset user:1 name lloyd likes whisky lives uk
OK

> sadd user:name:lloyd 1
(integer) 1

> sadd user:likes:whisky 1
(integer) 1

> sadd user:lives:uk 1
(integer) 1

> incr key:user
(integer) 2

> hmset user:2 name ivan likes whisky lives uk
OK

> sadd user:name:ivan 2
(integer) 1

> sadd user:like:whisky 2
(integer) 1

> sadd user:likes:whisky 2
(integer) 1

> sadd user:lives:nyc 2
(integer) 1

> hmset user:2 name ivan likes whisky lives nyc
OK

> hget user:2 name
"ivan"

> sunion user:likes:whisky user:lives:uk
1) "1"
2) "2"

> sinter user:likes:whisky user:lives:uk
1) "1"

> sdiff user:likes:whisky user:lives:uk
1) "2"

> sort user:likes:whisky by weight-* GET user:*->name
1) "lloyd"
2) "ivan"

> sort user:likes:whisky by weight-* GET user:*->name GET user:*->lives
1) "lloyd"
2) "uk"
3) "ivan"
4) "nyc"
```